# How can i pass the hidden parameters to Telerik Reports?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik, telerik-mvc, telerik-reporting

I develop MVC application in VS2010 and Telerik Reports  with "Telerik reporting Tool", it gives me a .trdx file so I integrated that report to my project with Uri `new Telerik.Reporting.UriReportSource()`; But now i want to pass some hidden parameters to this report

How can i do this? Please give me some advice

Thnx

Saul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found something. I hope it helps you. Maybe you can modify and use it

```
$('#btnUpdateReport').click(function () {
        // add the parameters to the controller parameters
        var pId = $('#txtPortfolioId').val();
        var viewer = $reportViewer.data('telerik_ReportViewer');
        viewer.reportSource($.extend({}, viewer.reportSource(), { parameters: { 'portfolioId': pId } }));
});
```

http://www.telerik.com/forums/external-report-viewer-parameters

Comment: Yes Thank you MustafaP I think this is way to send from javascript and i found the way to send parameter from server side however thank you for your answer :)